# AngularFire2 - AuthGuard thinks user isn't logged in, even though they are

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

I have an auth guard in place in my Angular 2 app for these routes, and I'm using Firebase for my authentication. What's weird is that I have the functionality sorted out for maintaining a logged in user on page refresh, however when I have my auth guards active on a route, it keeps telling me that the user isn't logged in. Can anyone explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

Here is the code for my auth guard:

```
constructor(private authService:AuthService, private router:Router) {

    }

    canActivate(route:ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state:RouterStateSnapshot):Observable<boolean> {

  return this.authService.getAuthenticated().map(authenticated => {
    if(authenticated) {
      return true;
    } else {
      this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    }
  }).take(1);
}
```

And then in my auth service, here's the code to ensure that the user is up-to-date:

```
  authInfo$: BehaviorSubject<AuthInfo> = new BehaviorSubject<AuthInfo>(AuthService.UNKNOWN_USER);


      constructor(private auth: AngularFireAuth, private router:Router) {
        auth.subscribe((authState) => {
         if (authState) {
           const authInfo = new AuthInfo(authState.uid);
           this.authInfo$.next(authInfo);
         }
       });
      }


// Added a method to return the auth to be checked against
getAuthenticated(): Observable<any> {
    return this.auth;
  }
```

Update: I updated my `canActivate` function and auth service to what works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be easier to merge your auth-guard and you service.

Here is an example of an authguard service I coded:

```
  private loggedIn: boolean = false;

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private af: AngularFire,
  ) {
    af.auth.subscribe(res => this.onAuthChange(res));
  }

  private onAuthChange(auth) {
    this.loggedIn = auth ? true : false;
  }

  canActivate(routeSnapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    if (this.loggedIn) {
      return true;
    }
    console.log('Route blocked by AuthGuardService');
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    return false;
  }
```

Comment: Oh awesome, this works nicely :) The thing I'm noticing is that even with this code, the logged in state is working when navigating through the app, but if I refresh on a page that has a route guard, it'll still redirect to the login page. Any clue what that might be?

Comment: Make sure your app.module.ts is the provider of your AuthGuardService.

Comment: Yeah, I've got that. What's interesting is that the check of the auth state is happening after the auth guard function. I'm not sure if that's a race condition or what, as the guard happens instantly, meanwhile my auth check happens asynchronously. Hmm any thoughts at what I might be able to do?

Comment: Oh you're right, the only solution I found was to check if the user was authenticated in the login.component's constructor and redirect him to the appropriate page.

Comment: It's okay, I got it all figured out :)

Comment: If you found another solution, I'm also interested :)

Comment: Yeah, I updated my code to reflect it. Just a couple of small changes :)